# Give a reason why $\mathbb Z_{64}\times \mathbb Z_4$ and $\mathbb Z_{64}\times \mathbb Z_{2}\times \mathbb Z_{2}$ are not isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

The question is about classifying groups of order $256$ with at least one element of order $64$, and *justify why the elements of the list are non-isomorphic*.
I'm done except for showing that
$$
  \mathbb Z_{64}\times \mathbb Z_{2}\times\mathbb Z_{2}\text{ and }
  \mathbb Z_{64}\times \mathbb Z_{4}
$$
are not isomorphic.
Of course they are not, that's the content of the classification theorem, but the question begs a direct approach.

All similar questions I found on MSE differentiate groups of this kind from order elements, e.g.  $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb Z_4$ are not isomorphic as only the latter contains an element of order 4.
We can't apply that here.

**My solution:**
the order of a an element of a product is the minimum common multiple of the non-zero orders.
Thus an element of $\mathbb Z_{64}\times \mathbb Z_{2}\times\mathbb Z_2$ has order 2 iff it's nonzero and its $\mathbb Z_{64}$ factor is $0$ or $32$ (the elements of order 2 in $\mathbb Z_{64}$).
We get a total of 7 elements of order 2,
$$
  (32,0,0),(0,1,0) ,(0,0,1)  ,(0,1,1)
  ,(32,1,0),(32,0,1)  \text{ and }(32,1,1).
$$
On the other hand, the same reasoning shows that there are only 3 elements of order 2 in $\mathbb Z_{64}\times\mathbb Z_{4}$, namely $$(32,0), (0,2) \text{ and }(32,2).$$

Is this correct? I think so, but I spent more time in this question than I'd like to admit, that's why I'm posting it. Any other approaches?

Comment: It is correct and you don't need anything else. Good job. Yet Mark Bennet has a very nice idea in his answer: one of the groups has $\;\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2\;$ as a subgroup, whereas the other one has *not* ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That was my first thought of a way to do it.

Depending on where you are in your learning you might be expected to show that if the first component is other than $0$ or $32$ the order is greater than $2$ (and similarly for the second component in the $\mathbb Z_4$ case). But the reasoning is completely sound.

You might also identify a subgroup $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ in one case rather than the other. Orders of elements and subgroups are two potentially distinguishing features to look out for.

Answer (score 3):

Draw the lattice of subgroups, maybe. The lattice of the Klein four group is not a total order, but that of  the cyclic group of order four is. Then note how doing $G\times -$ changes the lattice.